# Grid Hosting for Windows

Tags: .net, hosting

Are there any **good** grid-hosting companies out there that offer .NET stacks? Something like MediaTemple - which won't host the worlds fastest websites, but for the price is far better than "shared hosting". I've used Rackspace's Mosso, but it sucked - it never felt like a normal .NET stack (caching was odd, site recompilation was odd).

Comment: Did you ever talk to mosso support about your issues? I found that if I uploaded a App_Offine.htm file while updating my mosso site it stopped any issues with recompilation and caching.

Answer (score 5):

Try [gogrid.com](http://www.gogrid.com) they seem to have a very nice following in the cloud computing circles.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about Mosso .

http://www.mosso.com/

Answer (score 0):

can talk a bit more about the not so normal .net experience? I was thinking to go for Mosso...

Comment: I've been real happy on Mosso except for the caching.  It is a web farm and caching will cause some weirdness. It is server independent.  If you update something on your site, you need to delete web.config and reupload it to make all the servers in their web farm update it.  Mosso Support is awesome

Answer (score 0):

Grid Hosting one price , an entire cloud hosting server
[link text](http://www.ix-one.com/webhosting/Grid_Hosting.htm)